Most effective procedure to use face-detection and face-recognition with Digikam
I am running Digikam 7.5.0 on Ubuntu 22.04.4.  I have installed and enabled YOLO v3 for face-detection and face recognition.  I have set Face Accuracy to 80.
I started out by detecting all the faces in my photo collection and then identifying ~10 faces for about five people.  I then asked it to do face-recognition and it identified a 20-30 more for these people with some inaccuracy.  I accepted to correct identifications and for the incorrect I either identified who the face did belong to or I rejected the identification (the minus, -, sign)
Then I did a lot more identifying in my collection, identifying over a couple of days, maybe about 1000 faces.  These 1000 faces belong mostly to about 15 people (my close extended family) but I identified about 50 new people with anywhere from 1-5 faces each.  Then I re-ran face-recognition and the results were almost no improvement to my first recognition run!
I have tried

Maintenance->Detect and recognize faces->Clear and rebuild all training data;
Maintenance->Detect and recognize faces->Clear unconfirmed results and rescan;
People->Workflow->Scan again and merge results

multiple times and in different orders.  There have been a handful of new correct identifications from time to time and always the same incorrect identifications are proposed, even though I choose "Reject this suggestion" each time they were proposed.
I feel that I am not using the tool correctly and would like advice on using it better.

I’m voting to close this question because it has been cross-posted on Unix & Linux: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/774604/most-effective-procedure-to-use-face-detection-and-face-recognition-with-digikam . I get it, it's a niche question, and I'm sorry it can't get more visibility, however it's against SE rules to crosspost questions over the network. I can spare some rep to bounty it for you if you ping me once it's (bountiable?).

OK, I understand

It has been closed on Unix & Linux so I guess it'll stand here, if you don't get an answer in a few days let me know by pinging me using @kos and I'll bounty it. I suggest you reformat it a little bit better using paragraphs though, currently it's kinda hard to read.
